# Map over file tree, preserving structure

Tags: bash, find, make, basename, dirname

I have a file tree that looks like:

```
$ tree src
src
├── bible
│   ├── index.md
│   └── README.md
├── index.md
└── other.md
```

I want to render every Markdown file within this file tree to HTML via `pandoc(1)` -- **preserving structure**.

This new file tree should be rooted at `out`, like so:

```
$ tree out
out
├── bible
│   ├── index.html
│   └── README.html
├── index.html
└── other.html
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this via `make(1)`. This is what I have so far:

```
SRC_DIR=src
OUT_DIR=out

.PHONY: all
all: $(SRC_DIR)/*.md
    find . -name "*.md" -exec pandoc '{}' -o '{}'.html \;
    find -name "*.html" -exec bash -c 'mv {} $(OUT_DIR)/`dirname {}`/`basename {} .md.html`.html' \;
    # mv $(SRC_DIR)/*.html $(OUT_DIR)
    firefox $(OUT_DIR)/index.html

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm $(OUT_DIR)/*.html
```

This fails:

```
$ make
find . -name "*.md" -exec pandoc '{}' -o '{}'.html \;
find . -name "*.html" -exec bash -c 'mv {} `basename {} .md.html`.html' \;
mv src/*.html out
mv: cannot stat 'src/*.html': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the pathname of a single one of your `.md` files in `$pathname`, somewhere in or below `src`:

```bsh
name=$(basename "$pathname" .md)
destdir=out/$( dirname "${pathname#src/}" )
mkdir -p "$destdir" && pandoc -o "$destdir/$name.html" "$pathname"
```

Here, `basename "$pathname" .md` would be the file's name without the `.md` filename suffix and without any directory paths (e.g. `README` for `src/bible/README.md`), `${pathname#src/}` would be the the pathname of the file without the initial `src/` directory name and `$destdir` would be set to the destination directory pathname (`src/` exchanged for `out/`, no final filename component, e.g. `out/bible` for `src/bible/README.md`).  At the end, we let `pandoc` write to `$destdir/$name.html` (if the creation of the destination directory succeeded).

You can run this for all `.md` files in a directory structure:

```bsh
find src -type f -name '*.md' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        name=$(basename "$pathname" .md)
        destdir=out/$( dirname "${pathname#src/}" )
        mkdir -p "$destdir" && pandoc -o "$destdir/$name.html" "$pathname"
    done' {} +
```

This is the same set of commands in a loop. We let `find` feed the loop with pathnames found under `src` (see also [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)).

Testing:

```
$ tree -F
.
`-- src/
    |-- bible/
    |   |-- README.md
    |   `-- index.md
    |-- index.md
    `-- other.md

2 directories, 4 files
```

(command is being run here)

```
$ tree -F
.
|-- out/
|   |-- bible/
|   |   `-- README.html
|   |-- index.html
|   `-- other.html
`-- src/
    |-- bible/
    |   |-- README.md
    |   `-- index.md
    |-- index.md
    `-- other.md

4 directories, 7 files
```

If you want to use your `SRC_DIR` and `OUT_DIR` Makefile variables:

```bsh
find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -name '*.md' -exec sh -c '
    srcdir=${1%/}; outdir=$2; shift 2
    for pathname do
        name=$(basename "$pathname" .md)
        destdir=$outdir/$( dirname "${pathname#$srcdir/}" )
        mkdir -p "$destdir" && pandoc -o "$destdir/$name.html" "$pathname"
    done' $(SRC_DIR) $(OUT_DIR) {} +
```

That is, pass the src and out names on the `sh -c` script's command line and pick them out inside the in-line script.

I'm not 100% sure about how the quoting in a Makefile works, and you may want to escape the newlines in the code above, alternatively create a separate little script for doing this, and then call that from the Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the similarities in their  syntax, makefiles and shell scripts are as different as chalk from cheese.

You are writing a makefile in the spirit of a shell script. In make, we have to think in terms of relationships and dependencies. The shell comes into the picture only at the last stage as rules where dependencies are satisfied. These are called recipes in make parlance.

```
###### 
SHELL := /bin/sh

SRC_DIR := src
OUT_DIR := out

### recursive glob
**/* = $(foreach i,$(strip \
  $(wildcard $(1:=/*))),$(strip \
  $(call $0,$i,$2) \
  $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$i)))

MD_FILES = $(call **/*,$(SRC_DIR),*.md)

HTML_FILES = $(subst $(SRC_DIR)/,$(OUT_DIR)/,$(MD_FILES:.md=.html))

.PHONY: all
all: $(HTML_FILES)

.PHONY: make_dir
make_dir: $(OUT_DIR)/

$(OUT_DIR)/%.html: $(SRC_DIR)/%.md |make_dir
  pandoc $< -o $@

$(OUT_DIR)/: $(SRC_DIR)/
  rsync -avz -f"+ */" -f"- *" $< $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
  rm -f -- $(HTML_FILES)
```